# Converting the dtype of columns in pandas without column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, slice

I am working with data imported from a huge CSV. Pandas changed some columns to float, so now the numbers in these columns get displayed as floating points! However, I need them to be integers. I found some solutions, but all used the column names to change the dtypes.

Is there a way to change the data type for example for the first one thousand columns without addressing them separately by their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:, :1000] = df.iloc[:, :1000].astype(int)
```